# Plotting modes of circular waveguide in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm having some trouble with a script that I need to plot the TE and TM modes of a circular waveguide.
Everything is based on these formulas:
[image]

Right now I'm focused on the TE modes and what I have to plot is the field vector e_mn'' inside a squared-mesh equal to the radius of the waveguide. 
To do it I need to compute the bessel function of the first kind and extract x_mn that correspond to the n-th root in which the function is equal to zero. These points are supposed to be real but positive.
I followed this example
https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/community/22719-roots-of-a-bessel-function
but I get an error:

> Undefined function 'isfinite' for input arguments of type> 'function_handle'.
>  Error in roots (line 26) if ~all(isfinite(c))
>  Error
>   in circular (line 20)
>       x_mn=roots(J0)

This is my code. Can you help me?

```
clc
clear all
close all
a=20; %radius
m=0;    
n=1;


%%
if m==0
    ki_m=1;
else
ki_m=sqrt(2); 
end

r=0:0.1:a;
J0 = @(r) besselj(0,r);
    %J0 = besselj(m,r);
    %plot(J0)
    x_mn=roots(J0)
    %plot(J0(x_mn))
    %x_mn=abs(x_mn);
k_mn=x_mn./a;
F_mn=(ki_m*k_mn)./(J0(x_mn)*sqrt(pi*(x_mn^2-m^2)));

for r=0:1:a
    for phi=0:1*pi/180:2*pi
        e_mnR=-F_mn.*(J0(k_mn*r)/(k_mn.*r))*sin(m*phi);
        e_mnPHI=F_mn.*J0(k_mn*r)*cos(m*phi);
    end
end
e_mnR=abs(e_mnR);
e_mnPHI=abs(e_mnPHI);
X=0:1:a;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:1:a);
quiver(X,Y,e_mnR,e_mnPHI);
hold on
```

Comment: this error because J0 contains the besselj function handle not its result. if you want besselj to calculate r just use J0 = besselj(0,r);

Answer (score 0):

This is not my area of expertise so take this with a grain of salt, but I did some googling and think I know what's going on:

The code you are working from in the provided [link](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/community/22719-roots-of-a-bessel-function) defines:

```
J0 = chebfun(@(x) besselj(0,x),[0 100]);
```

Note the link from your reference to a Chebfun example is dead, but I read [here](http://www.chebfun.org/) that:

> Chebfun is an open-source package for computing with functions to about 15-digit accuracy. Most Chebfun commands are overloads of familiar MATLAB commands...

The only reason the example you cited works is because `J0` is defined using `Chebfun`, which overloads the matlab command `roots` with its own version that works on a function handle. Maybe read more [here](http://www.chebfun.org/) and try using this tool if you want to replicate that code example. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can use fzero instead of roots, but you confused polar and cartesian coordinates in the plot section and dimensions of vectors don't agree